# How can I perform this MySQL Trigger operation?

Tags: mysql

```
***OrdersTable***
ID    OrderNumber    CustomerId    Status
1     123456         1             0

***PurchasedProductsTable***
OrderId     itemSku     Qty
1           1000001     5
2           1000002     3

***TrackInventoriesTable***
CustomerId      ItemSku      OrderedQty
1               1000001      5
1               1000002      3
```

when customer cancel order (id 1) the Status from orders table is updated to 1. and when updated to status 1 trigger should run (not run when status is updated to 2 or 3).retrieves all the items of that order from purchased product table (here id 1 and 2). and loop is run on each item from purchased Product table and deducted that item quantity from itemQty column in trackinventories table (if itemSku from purchasedProducts and customerId from Orders table exactly matches).

the expected output should be 0 in orderedQty (in trackInventories table)for both Item sku (here 1000001 1000002) of that customer .

please help thanks.

Comment: 2 is not possible a trigger will fire on any change to the table. You would have to conditionally execute code in the trigger to achieve this.

Comment: will u please help me out with this :))

Comment: It isn't clear what your process is. 1 and 2 don't seem to warrant a trigger and I don't see what 3 could be a trigger on - it might be an insert on PurchasedProductsTable where the trigger would update TrackInventoriesTable

Comment: i have updated my lines please see :)

Comment: The trigger will always run but, as P.Salmon said, you can have all the code in a trigger wrapped in a condition so the code is only run when you want. Inside that block, you would just need to execute an update query on the other two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of your UPDATE trigger on the OrdersTable should look something like this:

```
IF NEW.Status = 1 
   AND OLD.Status <> 1 --Edit: Updates on other fields should not adjust quantities
BEGIN
    UPDATE TrackInventoriesTable AS ti 
    INNER JOIN PurchasedProductsTable AS pp ON ti.ItemSku = pp.ItemSku
    SET ti.OrderedQty = ti.OrderedQty - pp.Qty
    WHERE ti.CustomerId = NEW.CustomerId AND pp.OrderId = NEW.ID
    ;
END
```

However, if a single order can have multiple entries for the same sku, this probably won't quite work; if I remember correctly, MySQL UPDATE queries will only update a row once, even if the join would indicate multiple updates are needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; this should update every item associated with the order. My only concern with how I originally presented it would be if you have an update query that sets the status to 1, or updates a different field, when status is already 1, this would reduce the quantities again, but I just fixed that with a small edit.